# Source of a style tag inserted by style-loader from Webpack?

Tags: css, webpack

I'm using the `css-loader` and `style-loader` with Webpack. As expected, `style` tags get added to the `head` of the document, but there doesn't seem to be any way to determine which import led to a given style tag. My understanding is that the `css-loader` is responsible for reading the actual css files from the import, so it seems like something that should be configured with that loader. I can't find anything that would make that possible based on these docs though: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there's existing plugins and loaders to handle the need I mentioned, but I couldn't find any. I was able to get this custom loader working:
In `projectRoot/web_loaders/css-module-path-includer.js`:

```
module.exports = function (content) {
    return [
        `/* resource: ${this.resource} */`,
        content
    ].join('\n')
}
```

Updates to `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
   ...
   resolveLoader: {
     modules: [ 'node_modules', path.resolve(__dirname, "./web_loaders") ],
   },
   rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'css-module-path-includer'
        ],
      }
   ]
}
```

which gives you:
[image]

and then you can use something like this to track down which module in your source ultimately led to the import:
run

```
npx webpack --profile --json > stats.json
```

there was output before and after the actual json in the output that I had to edit. There's probably an argument that results in just the json being printed.

in `find_dependency_root.py`

```
import json
import sys

stats = json.loads(open('stats.json').read())
dependency = sys.argv[1]
visited = {}
dependency_chain = [dependency]
while True:
    module = next(module for module in stats['modules']
                  if dependency in str(module['id']))
    # try to account for circular dependencies
    if module['issuerId'] != 0 and dependency not in visited:
        visited[dependency] = True
        dependency = module['issuerId']
        dependency_chain.insert(0, dependency)
    else:
        print('\n'.join(dependency_chain))
        break
```

```
python3 find_dependency_root.py antd/lib/popover/style/index.css
```

```
./src/main/resources/static/js/Root.tsx
...
./node_modules/antd/lib/popconfirm/style/css.js
./node_modules/antd/lib/popover/style/css.js
antd/lib/popover/style/index.css
```